# GridView Pagination Links style

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview in my page with pagination implemented. I need to get rid of the underlines that automatically appear in the paging links.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  CssClass="grid" PagerStyle-Font-Underline="false"  AllowPaging="True"  OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging">         

               <HeaderStyle BackColor="#E6E6E6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#000000" />
              <PagerStyle CssClass="mpager"  HorizontalAlign="Right" />

                </asp:GridView>
```

and css:

```
.mpager span a
{ 
 text-decoration:none;  
}
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: I aplogize for the missing code...Steve I had tried your approach but didn't quiet do the trick..

Answer (score 1):

You have to set PagerStyle to change the appearance of the pager row. To remove the underline set the CssClass.

```
<PagerStyle CssClass="nounderline" />
```

Then define a selector to remove the underline from the hyperlinks contained in your pager row.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .nounderline a
    {
        text-decoration:none;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The source for your gv isn't showing, but try this:

```
.mpager a 
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

The span element contains the selected page, which isn't an anchor, so that's not what you want to target.